# Как проверить не является ли полученная на вход коллекция неизменной

Tags: java, исключения, коллекции

Мой метод получает на вход List и далее происходит его сортировка. При входных данных

```
List<Integer> input = Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);
```

Возникает ошибка.
Как проверить перед сортировкой не является ли коллекция ,данная на вход не изменяемой,
или как еще можно избежать ошибки. Спасибо

Comment: Начните сортировать, поймайте ошибку при попытке записи в коллекцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метода для проверки, является ли список неизменяемым, не существует, так как существует несколько разновидностей *неизменяемых* списков, которые можно создать разными способами:

- `Collections.nCopies`
- `Collections.unmodifiableList()`
- `Collections.singletonList()`
- `Collections.emptyList()`
- `List.of` (Java 9+)
- `Stream::toList` (Java 16+)
  Даже список, возвращаемый `Arrays.asList` *частично* неизменяемый, так как в нём нельзя изменять количество элементов (добавлять/удалять), но порядок элементов в нём (при той же сортировке) может изменяться, так как метод `set` не выбрасывает исключение.

---

Если *очень нужно*, чтобы не выбрасывалось `UnsupportedOperationException` при сортировке, можно реализовать собственный метод:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean trySort(List<T> list) {
    try {
        Collections.sort(list);
        return true;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException unsupex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Если *очень нужно* получить любой отсортированный список из некоторого исходного списка, можно создать изменяемую копию списка, отсортировать и вернуть её:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sorted(List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}
```

Или же использовать Stream API:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sorted(List<T> list) {
    return list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо !  Очень помогло