# В чем отличие объявление переменных HashMap от Map?

Tags: java

В чем отличие если мы объявим переменную так:

```
HashMap<Type, Type> lala = new HashMap<>();
```

Или так:

```
Map<Type, Type> lala = new HashMap<>();
```

В чем практическое отличие, почему в некоторых случаях объявляют как в первом случае, а в других как во втором. Так же касается и ArrayList

Comment: Что такое чистый код?

Answer (score 3):

Отличие в том, что во втором случае `lala` объявляется как ссылка на интерфейс `Map`, а в первом -- на конкретную реализацию `HashMap` этого интерфейса.  Соответственно, во втором случае можно легко переприсвоить переменной `lala` какую-нибудь другую реализацию:

```java
Map<String, Integer> lala = new HashMap<>();
lala = new TreeMap<>(lala); // получить отсортированную мапу
```

Особой разницы в данном случае между двумя указанными способами нет, так как `HashMap` не имеет каких-то своих особых методов, не объявленных в интерфейсе, в отличие от реализации `TreeMap` (для которой, впрочем существуют расширенные интерфейсы `SortedMap` / `NavigableMap`).

Первый способ позволяет воспользоваться полным функционалом, реализованным в классе, без дополнительного приведения типа.

Второй помогает уменьшить связанность кода и поэтому может считаться более предпочтительным, так как в таком случае в коде создаётся зависимость от абстракции (интерфейса), а не конкретной реализации.

---

То же относится и к связке `List` / `ArrayList`.  Например, если нужно пользоваться методами доступа к элементам списка по индексу `get(int index)` / `set(int index, E elem)`, то придётся использовать конкретную реализацию:

```java
ArrayList<Foo> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
arrList.add(new Foo(1));
arrList.set(0, new Foo(2));
```

Но в основном, при создании списков [другими способами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1383948/386633): `Arrays.asList`, `List.of`, и др. гораздо удобнее пользоваться общим интерфейсом, не вдаваясь в детали реализации:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); // java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
List<Integer> copies = Collections.nCopies(5, 10); // java.util.Collections$CopiesList
List<String> strs = List.of("a", "b"); // java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12
```

Answer (score 1):

тут надо понимание интерфейсов и коллекций.
если в двух словах `Map`, как и `List` интерфейсы, которые реализуют коллекции типа HashMap и ArrayList и т.д. а также реализуют все методы интерфейса.
Проще обращаться именно к интерфейсу, или так скажем, к более общему объекту/классу/сущности, нежели к ее конкретной реализации

```
public void someMethod(List<String> list)  {
}
```

В этот метод можем передавать ArrayList, LinkedList и любую другую коллекцию, реализующую List.

так же переприсвоить другую реализацию ссылки

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

              list = new ArrayList<>();
```

по этому принципу работает ключевое слово var

```
var list = new ArrayList<>();
```